# Datacontext not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I'm new to the EF- framework and I have problems loading my data.

Following code is working :

```
 var data = projectContext.Klanten;

        foreach (Klant klant in data)
        {
            KlantViewModel p = new KlantViewModel(klant);
            if (klant != null)
            {

                this.Klanten.Add(p);
            }
        }
```

The Foreach is executed.
But when I try to use a query on the same table

```
public void LaadKlanten()
    {
        ProjectContext dbContext = new ProjectContext();

        Klanten = new Dictionary<int, KlantManager>();
        var list = (from k in dbContext.Klanten
                    join p in dbContext.Projecten on k.KlantId equals p.KlantId
                    where k.KlantId == p.KlantId
                    select k);
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var klant in list)
        {
            i++;
            Klanten.Add(i, new KlantManager(klant));
        }
    }
```

The foreach is stopped immediately

Comment: instead `var` can you try explicit types?

Comment: When you debug it, what is `list`'s value?

Comment: stays the same, I replaced var with IQueryable<Klant>

Comment: I found the problem. I changed my datacontext, so my database was rebuild and the data from project table was cleared. Stupid mistake. Thanks for the effort.